# Re-use aliased field in SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, alias

I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
SELECT 
  (CASE WHEN ...) AS FieldA,
  FieldA + 20 AS FieldB
FROM Tbl
```

Assuming that by "..." I've replaced a long and complex **CASE** statement, **I don't want to repeat** it when selecting `FieldB` and use the aliased `FieldA` instead.

Note, that this will return multiple rows, hence the `DECLARE`/`SET` outside the `SELECT` statement is no good in my case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A workaroud would be to use a sub-query:

```
SELECT
  FieldA,
  FieldA + 20 AS FieldB
FROM (
  SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN ...) AS FieldA
  FROM Tbl
) t
```

---

To improve readability you could also use a [`CTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN ...) AS FieldA
  FROM Tbl
)
SELECT
  FieldA,
  FieldA + 20 AS FieldB
FROM
  t
```

Comment: Personally I find the derived table easier to read, but that's just me.

Answer (score 3):

When I have complicated logic to compute a "virtual" column value from other column values in a table I generally create a single-table view of the original table with all the original columns plus the computed values as well.  Then I do other SELECTs against the view.  That allows me:

1. To name my computed columns.
2. To keep the logic for the computations in one place instead of scattered through various queries in the application.

Comment: Will make no difference to performance *unless* you're using an engine that offers materialized views and you create this as a materialized view, in which case you'll decrease write performance but increase query performance.