# PostgreSQL - Avoid repeating a subquery to do a null check

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, common-table-expression

I'm trying to identify some items in a table that refer in manually-entered text to the identifiers of items in another table. The data structure is poorly-designed and doesn't have something to use for a simple join between the tables; they are out of sync.

I have this and it works, it's just not very pleasant:

```sql
SELECT i.id, (
     SELECT c.text
     FROM charges c
     WHERE c.text LIKE CONCAT('%', i.order, '%')
     AND c.state = 'paid'
) AS "charge text"
FROM items i
WHERE i.state = 'not paid'
AND (
     SELECT c.text
     FROM charges c
     WHERE c.text LIKE CONCAT('%', i.order, '%')
     AND c.state = 'paid'
) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id
```

Example data in `charges`:

```
id    state    text
------------------------------------------
1     paid     Lorem ipsum ABC123 sit amet
2     not paid DEF456 lorem ipsum sit amet
```

Example data in `items`:

```
id    state    order
---------------------
1     not paid ABC123
2     not paid DEF456
```

At present I need the second instance of the subquery to remove instances where a NULL reason has been selected as a result of examining every `i.number`. I'd like to avoid having the subquery appear twice, but it doesn't appear that I can use a [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) (`WITH`, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2446851/3358139)) because it would be defined at the start and so I couldn't pass `i.number` into it. I may be wrong about this as I haven't used CTEs before.

So I guess I have two questions - firstly, can I define the subquery once and then just check the result as NOT NULL; and secondly, am I coming at this wrong and there's a better way to do the query that obviates the necessity for that check?

Comment: why do you need a correlated sub-query when you can use a `join`?

Comment: Respectfully - you tell me? I don't get much from that as a reply.

Comment: @Scott: The implied answer is, "you don't".

Comment: @cHao: Yes, I'm quite capable of reading. That's equally unhelpful.

Comment: @Scott: Is it? I guess there's an unstated assumption that you understand how joins work, and by extension, how to turn your subquery into a join. (In this case, it's rather trivial, just use the same condition you did for the subquery.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this properly as a join. Correlated subqueries are best used when you don't need the results of the subquery in your result set. In this case you do, so just join:

```
SELECT
    i.id,
    c.txt
FROM items i
    INNER JOIN charges c ON
        c.text like CONCAT('%', i.order , '%')
WHERE
    c.state = 'paid'
    AND i.state = 'unpaid'
```

You can add the `AND c.txt IS NOT NULL` to that WHERE clause, but with the INNER JOIN it's probably unlikely to catch anything that isn't already suppressed by the join itself.

Also, I did away with the subquery since you aren't aggregating or doing any other logic that can't be done in the main query itself.

Comment: OK - perfect. My problem here was not knowing that a join can be done on a like. Thank you.

Comment: That makes sense! You can get pretty crazy in your JOIN. It's not going to be very fast with a LIKE, but it gets the job done. The correlated subquery is going to end up acting exactly like a JOIN anyway, so it's 6 of one, half a dozen of the other.

Answer (score 0):

In general you could use `LATERAL JOIN`:

```
SELECT i.id, sub."charge text"
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN LATERAL 
(
     SELECT c.text AS "charge text"
     FROM charges c
     WHERE c.text LIKE CONCAT('%', i.order, '%')
     AND c.state = 'paid'
) sub ON true
WHERE i.state = 'not paid'
AND  sub."charge text" IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id;
```

---

```
SELECT i.id, sub."charge text"
FROM items i
JOIN LATERAL 
(
     SELECT c.text AS "charge text"
     FROM charges c
     WHERE c.text LIKE CONCAT('%', i.order, '%')
     AND c.state = 'paid'
) sub ON true
WHERE i.state = 'not paid'
ORDER BY id;
```