# use recently defined alias in sql in case when

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to clean up a product column in a sql table when querying. My (fake example) query looks like the following:

```
select
Id
, Name
, ProductName
, CASE
   WHEN ProductName IN ('macbook', 'dell', 'air', 'hp') THEN 'Laptop'
   WHEN ProductName IN ('ipod', 'walkman', 'headset') THEN 'Music_Device'
   WHEN ProductName IN ('mop', 'broom', 'sponge') THEN 'Household Utilities'
   WHEN ProductName IN ('bike', 'bike_2', 'bike_3') THEN 'Bicycle'
   WHEN ProductName IN ('tesla', 'ford', 'prius') THEN 'Car'
   ELSE null
   END AS Prod_Group
, CASE
   WHEN Prod_Group IN ('Laptop', 'Music_Device') THEN 'Electronics'
   WHEN Prod_Group IN ('Bicycle', 'Car') THEN 'Transportation'
   WHEN Prod_Group IN ('Household Utilities') THEN 'Utilities'
   ELSE null
   END AS Line_of_Business
from prod_database
```

Is there no way to reference an aliased column? Would I have to repeat my whole case when statement and change `Laptop` to `Electronics` etc.? I'm coming from R and learning SQL, so this is a bit new to me.

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`? Anyway, google CTEs, and that should cover either, or subqueries for older dialects maybe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reusing alias in SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072479/reusing-alias-in-select) (MySQL)

Comment: and for SQL Server, since you can't seem to pick just one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446843/re-use-aliased-field-in-sql-select-statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-use aliased field in SQL SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446843/re-use-aliased-field-in-sql-select-statement)

Comment: sorry- sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sql Server, we can use `Cross Apply`

```
SELECT Id,
       NAME,
       ProductName,
       cs.Prod_Group,
       CASE
         WHEN cs.Prod_Group IN ( 'Laptop', 'Music_Device' ) THEN 'Electronics'
         WHEN cs.Prod_Group IN ( 'Bicycle', 'Car' ) THEN 'Transportation'
         WHEN cs.Prod_Group IN ( 'Household Utilities' ) THEN 'Utilities'
         ELSE NULL
       END AS Line_of_Business
FROM   prod_database
       CROSS apply (SELECT CASE
                             WHEN ProductName IN ( 'macbook', 'dell', 'air', 'hp' ) THEN 'Laptop'
                             WHEN ProductName IN ( 'ipod', 'walkman', 'headset' ) THEN 'Music_Device'
                             WHEN ProductName IN ( 'mop', 'broom', 'sponge' ) THEN 'Household Utilities'
                             WHEN ProductName IN ( 'bike', 'bike_2', 'bike_3' ) THEN 'Bicycle'
                             WHEN ProductName IN ( 'tesla', 'ford', 'prius' ) THEN 'Car'
                             ELSE NULL
                           END) cs (Prod_Group)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to with a CTE I suppose...

```
    WITH CTE
    AS
        (
          SELECT CASE WHEN 1>0 THEN 'A' END AS derivedCol
        )
    SELECT CASE WHEN derivedCol < 'B' THEN 'Pos1' ELSE 'Other' END
    FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--could use a real table here
declare @prodTypes as table
  (ProductName varchar(50),
  ProductGroup varchar(50),
  Line_of_Business varchar(50));

insert into @prodTypes
values ('macbook', 'Laptop', 'Electronics'),
('dell', 'Laptop', 'Electronics'),
('hp', 'Laptop', 'Electronics'),
('ipod', 'Music_Device', 'Electronics')
-- etc.


-- the results you want:
select
  p.Id
, p.Name
, p.ProductName
, pt.ProductGroup
, pt.Line_of_Business
from prod_database p
left join @prodTypes pt
on p.ProductName = pt.ProductName


-- to double check your settings you can do:
select Line_of_business, ProductGroup, ProductName
from @prodTypes 
order by Line_of_business, ProductGroup, ProductName
```